# When is the floating-point positive zero not all-bit zero?

Tags: c, floating-point

In C, the [empty initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization#Empty_initialization) intializes a floating-point variable to be positive zero. It says that

> (on platforms where null pointer values and floating zeroes have all-bit-zero representations, this form of initialization for statics is normally implemented by allocating them in the .bss section of the program image)

So, what is the actual platform or floating-point format that makes the positive zero not all-bit zero?

Comment: IEEE754 floating point representation implements positive 0 as all-bits-zero, and most systems you're likely to come across use that, so you'd need to find a system that doesn't use that representation.

Comment: At one time, floating-point representations varied widely from vendor to vendor, but not nearly so much these days.  If you're interested in *historical* FP formats where positive zero was not all-bit-zero then [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better place to ask.  Not that I'm certain there ever were any such formats in reality, but the C language spec allows them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any modern platforms with non-IEEE C/C++ float formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724359/are-there-any-modern-platforms-with-non-ieee-c-c-float-formats)

Comment: C23 has not yet been released so `= {}` is invalid C still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is the floating-point positive zero not all-bit zero?

There is a hidden assumption in OP's question that there is only 1 *floating-point positive zero* encoding.

Up to 201x, a good compiler for embedded targets is CCS. It used a [non IEEE `float`](https://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=mchp_float_format):

1st byte: 8-bit biased exponent
2nd byte: sign bit and 7 MS Bits of *mantissa*
3rd byte: 8 more bits of *mantissa*
4th byte: 8 LS Bits of *mantissa*

It did not support subnormals.  Any 00-XX-XX-XX was a "zero".

Code like `float x = 0.0;` would make `x` a positive zero with an all zero bit pattern.

`uint32_t y = 0x001122; memcpy(&x, &y, 4);` would make `x` a positive zero with a non-zero bit pattern.

---

A narrower question would be the following, which better addresses OP's concern.

> When is the floating-point *initialization* to positive zero not all-bit zero?